# WAMP server shows Just-In-Time debugger error when starting

Tags: windows-xp, wamp

I've installed WampServer 2.2 on my Windows XP system. After that I installed Visual Studio 2010.

After one month I uninstalled Visual Studio 2010 from my system. And when I start WampServer, it is showing this error:

[image: ss]

Anybody knows how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried re-installing WAMP?

Comment: @Rabbid10 Yes, tried so many times.